# Is this representation correct although it seems to show a pentavalent carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

While I was trying to draw a possible representation of $\ce{(CH3O)2CH=CHCH(OCH3)2}$ I was perplexed  by the fact that from left to right the second carbon atom has a double bound with the third one, while at the same time it is connected to two methyl groups, plus the H element.  That makes five bounds.
I found this as an answer:

$\hspace{25ex}$ [image]

But in my opinion, in the image, the double bound is misplaced as it should be on the from the first carbon atom after O.
I am stuck here.

Comment: The formula you have there is impossible because as you recognized, there is a carbon with five bonds.

Comment: @pigeon Your condensed formula corresponds to $\ce{C7H15O4}$, whereas your structural formula corresponds to $\ce{C8H16O4}$.

Comment: That's right, the molecule is symmetric around the double bond, and so should be the formula. One CH is missing.

Comment: Yes that is right . i did not notice this one! It is a mistake made in the book i am reading from.

Comment: Also the structure you have drawn has 8 carbons but the formula you give only has 7.

Comment: So, did you send a bug report to J. Clayden and S. Warren?